# creating columns and rows; asking for the number of lines the user wants to output then the display

Tags: c++, rows, multiple-columns

```
//libraries
#include <iostream>

//global constants

//no functioning prototypes
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //Define variables
    int n; // Number of rows
    int i; // Row count in for loop
    int k; // Output for loop

    // Have user input n
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> n;

    // Complete for loop
    for (i = 1; i <= n + 1; i++){
    for (k = 1; k < i; k++){
    cout << k%10;
}
  cout << endl;
}

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm trying to create a code that is similar to this except instead of out putting

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I need it to look like

```
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
```

where the ending number is the number of columns is the number entered and spaces instead of the numbers previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to replace this line:

```
cout << k%10;
```

for this line:

```
if (k<i-1) cout << ' '; else cout << k%10;
```

That prints the number if we are in the last position of the current row, or a space if we aren't.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"iostream"
#include"conio.h"
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int a=1;
int n;
cout<<"enter the lenght of the numbers";
cin>>n;

for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    {for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        if (j==a)
            cout<<j;
        else cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    a=a+1;
}

_getch();   
}
```